# tbb parallel_for crashes when the number of threads exceeds the maxproc on the system

Tags: multithreading, tbb

During Parallel_for execution, tbb crashes with the following message:
thread_monitor Resource temporarily unavailable in pthread_create

Does tbb throw an exception when it encounters this problem ? So that I can catch it and issue an error message and then terminate